# Keep in cart only last added item from specific product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, taxonomy-terms

I have a situation where user cannot add more than 1 product to cart from specific category. I tried using `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter hook.

This code works for all items and keep in cart last added item:

```
// before add to cart, only allow 1 item in a cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart_before' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart_before( $cart_item_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    
    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return true;
}
```

This code doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart_before' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart_before( $cart_item_data ) {
    if( is_product_category( 'test' ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Do nothing with the data and return
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: In the working version, you returned true in any case - in the second one, you are now only doing that if the category was test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'only_allow_one_item_from_specific_category', 10, 1 );
function only_allow_one_item_from_specific_category( $cart ){
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its sort of working but its not allowing to add another product from same category, it should replace the cart with the latest added to cart item pls?

Comment: Do you want to override product from the same category?

Comment: yep correct, override with  the last added to cart item

Comment: didn't worked, its allowing to add me product from same category

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_maybe_empty_cart( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    if( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
  if( ! empty ( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) && $valid ){
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    wc_add_notice( 'Only allowed 1 item in cart.', 'error' );
  }
}
 }
 return $valid;
  }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_maybe_empty_cart', 10, 3 );
```

This code worked for me pls. Thank you so much for helping everyone.